# A user has to double click on Browse button in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the following code for my Browse button to select a file ,

```
<form>
    <input type="file">
</form>

$("input").click(function() { 
    $(this).dblclick(); 
});
```

This works well on Chrome and Mozilla as a user does on single click and a popup window opens

However on IE a user has to double click to open the file browse .
Please suggest suitable approach to handle this in IE to make it work for a single click.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Why not just let the click happen as it should?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`

Comment: As initially the tester found a defect on IE that a user needs to double click on Browse button , a single click should work in IE however I had to change the code to use a Jquery thats why.

Comment: this tester probably had his window not focussed. Test again ;)

Comment: I agree with Rene. There is no reason for the extra Javascript. If the problem persists for your tester, try again with IE on a different computer. In a properly-working environment, only a single click will be required.

Comment: I tested this on QA site where the code is deployed and yes a user has to click twice wherein Chrome only needs a single click

Comment: Did you test it with or without your added Javascript click handler?

Comment: You need to single click the "browse" button, not the entire field.

Comment: Just tested in IE10 and confirmed that you don't need to double-click the "Browse" button. If you want to invoke the file upload dialog by clicking on the input value field, then you do need to click twice quickly. Why mess with this though? Users of IE are already going to be familiar with this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using Javascript for this, in IE its should popup the file select window in single click, but as per browser may change the button caption and location, in IE the caption would be "Browse" but in Chrome it would be "Choose File"

Comment: It should happen that way you mentioned bu When I tested the same and I need to double click on browse button to open a pop-up on IE

Comment: which version of IE are you using?